# How can I find the number closest to being rounded?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need an algorithm to round off all of the numbers in an `unrounded` list, resulting in a `rounded` list with given sum.  So far, my logic is an iterative approximation:

```
while rounded != unrounded:
    if rounded > unrounded:
        ***find number closest to rounding down***
```

For instance, consider this unrounded list

```
[132.86, 57.78, 132.52, 137.36, 44.98, 97.05, 55.01, 26.64, 
 136.84, 75.08, 83.56, 21.28, 0.00, 0.00]
```

The sum is 1000.96; I need a list of whole numbers that sum to 1000.  When I simply round each float to the nearest whole number, I have

```
[133.0, 58.0, 133.0, 137.0, 45.0, 97.0, 55.0, 27.0, 137.0, 75.0, 84.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Which sums to 1002.  In this example, I need to find a way to make 132.52 and 83.56 from the unrounded list round down to make up the difference.  I have to change those two: of the numbers rounded up, they had the smallest fractional parts.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to solve the subset sum problem.

Comment: I don't believe I am, I just worded my original post poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand: your list has a sum *close* to the desired result (1000), but you want to round each of the numbers up or down, so that the sum is exactly 1000.

Also, you want to determine which numbers to round up, and which down, so that the ones with the higher fractional parts get rounded up.  In the case above, you did a simple rounding off, but came up with a sum of 998 ... so you want to round up the next two lowest fractional parts (.52 and .56), to get the sum of 1000.

To do this, you need simpler steps:

(1) get the approximate sum from rounding everything in the same direction, so you can figure out how many items to round in each direction.  You can do this simply by mapping `int` to the list and taking the sum of the result:

```
lower_sum = sum(map(int(myList))
```

(2) Now, you need to round *up* a certain quantity of elements, that being `round_up = 1000 - lower_sum`.

(3) Sort the list according to the *fractional* part of each number as the key.

```
fract_sort = sorted(myList, key = lambda x:x%1)
```

(4) Now, just round up the last `round_up` elements of the `fract_sort`.

Specific coding is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I am looking for. I'm not a student anywhere, learning to code is just something the has piqued my interest.

Comment: You're a student :-)  You don't need a formal school to claim the title.

Comment: If this proves to satisfy your needs, I'll emend the question.

Comment: The sum is coming out to 1002, same concept but I need to round down (.52, .56).

Comment: No problem -- the solution above ignores rounding to *nearest* altogether.  It rounds everything *down* (integer truncation on positive numbers), and then looks to see how many have to be rounded *up* to get the desired sum.  We start at 995, and then round up the last 5 numbers in the sorted list.

Answer (score 3):

You can just map the round function:

```
myList = [132.86, 57.78, 132.52, 137.36, 44.98, 97.05, 55.01, 26.64, 136.84, 75.08, 83.56, 21.28, 0.00, 0.00]

print([*map(round, myList)])

=> [133, 58, 133, 137, 45, 97, 55, 27, 137, 75, 84, 21, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's sum up what you have right now:

```
the_list = [132.86, 57.78, 132.52, 137.36, 44.98, 97.05, 55.01, 26.64, 136.84, 75.08, 83.56, 21.28, 0.00, 0.00]
print sum(the_list)
>>> 1000.96
```

No surprise there, but we did not yet floor it. So let's do so:

```
import math
the_list = [132.86, 57.78, 132.52, 137.36, 44.98, 97.05, 55.01, 26.64, 136.84, 75.08, 83.56, 21.28, 0.00, 0.00]
the_list = [math.floor(x) for x in the_list]
print sum(the_list)
>>> 995.0
```

Okay, too low. *Some* of the values should be rounded up (a.k.a., probably "correctly") – but not *all* of them. See?

```
print sum([round(x) for x in the_list])
>>> 1002.0
```

So only some values must be rounded up, others rounded down. How do we choose which numbers to round up? Starting with the highest (fraction), of course:

```
max_frac = sorted(the_list, key=lambda x: x - math.floor(x))
print max_frac
>>> [0.0, 0.0, 55.01, 97.05, 75.08, 21.28, 137.36, 132.52, 83.56, 26.64, 57.78, 136.84, 132.86, 44.98]
```

... and the highest fraction is the one at the end. We even know how many numbers need rounding up:

```
1000 - sum([math.floor(x) for x in the_list])
>>> 5.0
```

We don't use `math.ceil` to increase those numbers because that would fail for a simple list `[1.33,1.33,1.34]`; instead, we use `math.floor(x)+1`. That leads us to a complete solution

```
import math

the_list = [132.86, 57.78, 132.52, 137.36, 44.98, 97.05, 55.01, 26.64, 136.84, 75.08, 83.56, 21.28, 0.00, 0.00]

the_list_a = [math.floor(x) for x in the_list]
diff = int(1000 - sum(the_list_a))
max_frac = sorted(the_list, key=lambda x: x - math.floor(x))[-diff:]
for m in max_frac:
    the_list_a[the_list.index(m)] = math.floor(m)+1
print the_list_a
print sum(the_list_a)
>>> [133.0, 58.0, 132.0, 137.0, 45.0, 97.0, 55.0, 27.0, 137.0, 75.0, 83.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> 1000.0
```